# Search MongoDB Array of Objects in any order

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection with an array of objects. I want to be able to search the objects in the array in any order and only return a match if all objects in that array are found.

My collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5234c367354kj63c9cae4fec"),
    "field1" : "TEST",
    "created" : <DATE_HERE>,
    "field2" : [ 
        {
            "index" : "A",
            "value" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "index" : "B",
            "value" : "2"
        }, 
        {
            "index" : "C",
            "value" : "3"
        }
    ],
}
```

If I provide the query below, the above document will get returned, because all 3 objects are given in the exact order that they're stored.

```
db.collection("collection").find({field1: "TEST", field2: [{"index": "A", "value": "1"}, {"index": "B", "value": "2"}, {"index": "C", "value": "3"}]})
```

However, I want to be able to find the document above given the 3 objects in any order. For example the query below:

```
db.collection("collection").find({field1: "TEST", field2: [{"index": "B", "value": "2"}, {"index": "A", "value": "1"}, {"index": "A", "value": "1"}]})
```

I know the above query won't work, if it's even possible, and is missing the correct syntax/search function, but it's just to explain my thought process and what i'm trying to achieve.

I've tried using the `$in` search with something like `field2: {$in: [<3_objects_above>]}`, but it won't give me an exact match. For example, if there's a 2nd document in this collection with `field2: [...{"index": "Z", "value": "543"}]` and it contains just 1 of 3 of the objects shown in the 2 queries and table above, this 2nd document would get returned as well because it matched at least 1 object provided in the array even though i didn't provide the object `{"index": "Z", "value": "543"}`.

Is there a way to accomplish giving objects in an array in any order and find the document in a collection that matches all 3 objects no matter what order they're given in? Matches **all 3 not any of the 3**?

Comment: No as i didn't know about that one, but i just tested and that worked!!! Thank you! Can you please respond to the post so i can accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator:

```
db.collection.find(
   {
      field1: "TEST",
      field2: {
         $all: [
            { "index": "A", "value": "1" },
            { "index": "B", "value": "2" },
            { "index": "C", "value": "3" }
         ]
      }
   }
)
```